# MFC - Blurry / Pixelized BMP with StretchDIBits

Tags: mfc

I am using the StretchDIBits function and during the display of the bitmap, I can see that it is displayed in two different ways such as below :

[image: Blurry BMP]
[image: Pixel BMP]

The only thing that I am doing is updating the BMP buffer whenever I get new data.

Please find below the associated code that is used to display the bitmap.

```
if (pBMPBuffer)
{
    LPBITMAPINFO pBmpInfo;
    pBmpInfo = (LPBITMAPINFO) new BYTE[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD)];

    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth = m_iZSize;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight = m_iXSize;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = m_iXSize * m_iZSize;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    pBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    SetStretchBltMode(pDC->m_hDC, STRETCH_HALFTONE);
    StretchDIBits(pDC->m_hDC,
                  rectBMP.left,
                  rectBMP.top,
                  rectBMP.Width(),
                  rectBMP.Height(),
                  0,
                  0,
                  m_iZSize,
                  m_iXSize,
                  pBMPBuffer,
                  pBmpInfo,
                  DIB_RGB_COLORS,
                  SRCCOPY);

    delete[] pBmpInfo;
}
```

I would like to have the bitmap always with the "blurry" look.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation states you should always use `SetBrushOrgEx` after `SetStretchBltMode`, have you tried that?

Comment: Hi Mark, I just tried and it is now displaying "only" the pixel type. Do you have any idea how I could get the "blurry" one ?

Comment: Sorry, if I did I would have answered the question. The only thing I can suggest is varying the parameters to `SetBrushOrgEx`.

Comment: It is pretty much like the HALFTONE is failing for a reason. I will keep checking and post here when I get an answer. Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use GDI+ instead of GDI and select a bicubic interpolation algorithm to be used when images are scaled or rotated. [See Gdiplus::Graphics::SetInterpolationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535810(v=vs.85).aspx)

Notice that GDI+ is going to be slower than GDI.. Another option would be using OpenGL for example...

Comment: This is working. I used the DrawImage methods of Graphics to display the bitmap. Thanks.